# When does duck typing matter or apply?

Tags: programming-languages, computer-science, duck-typing

Does duck typing matter/apply only when

- a programming language doesn't declare the type of any object, and
- objects are passed as arguments to a function and are used inside the function to access the methods provided by the types of the objects?

In other words, if a programming language requires declaration the type of any object, or if objects are used in ways other than passed as arguments to a function and used inside the function to access the methods of their types, does duck typing still matter/apply?

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is not clear to me: what do you mean by "does it still matter" ? matters in what sense ?

Comment: "matter" means "apply" or "make sense" in the case that I mentioned.

Comment: I know the meaning of the word, what I don't understand is the meaning of your question...

Comment: "if a programming language requires declaration the type of any object" - then it's a strongly typed language (compile-time) - not a duck-typed one (run-time).

Comment: Thanks. Yes, you got what I meant by duck typing "doesn't apply" when "a programming language requires declaration the type of any object". How about the case when objects are used in ways other than "passed as arguments to a function and used inside the function to access the methods of their types", assuming no declaration of type for any object?

Comment: How the objects are used is irrelevant.

Comment: I originally thought the same, but now I can't think of a use case other than arguments to functions, where duck typing matters. Could you?